# Adding Extension Type to XSD schema for HERE API

Tags: java, xsd, schema

I have been given a task to extend an xsd schema for the HERE API. Currently the schema we have is as follows: (Quite big)

```
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1" targetNamespace="http://www.topografix.com/GPX/1/1"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:documentation>
        GPX schema version 1.1 - For more information on GPX and this schema,
        visit http://www.topografix.com/gpx.asp GPX uses the following
        conventions: all coordinates are relative to the WGS84 datum. All
        measurements are in metric units.
    </xsd:documentation>
</xsd:annotation>
<xsd:element name="gpx" type="gpxType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>GPX is the root element in the XML file.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
<xsd:complexType name="gpxType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            GPX documents contain a metadata header, followed by waypoints, routes,
            and tracks. You can add your own elements to the extensions section
            of the GPX document.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="metadata" type="metadataType"
            minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Metadata about the file.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="wpt" type="wptType" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>A list of waypoints.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="rte" type="rteType" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>A list of routes.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="trk" type="trkType" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>A list of tracks.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="extensions" type="extensionsType"
            minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    You can add extend GPX by adding your own elements from another
                    schema here.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="version" type="xsd:string" use="required"
        fixed="1.1">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                You must include the version number in your GPX document.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="creator" type="xsd:string" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                You must include the name or URL of the software that created your GPX
                document. This allows others to inform the creator of a GPX
                instance document that fails to validate.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="metadataType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Information about the GPX file, author, and copyright restrictions goes in the
            metadata section. Providing rich, meaningful information about your
            GPX files allows others to search for and use your GPS data.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <!-- elements must appear in this order -->
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>The name of the GPX file.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="desc" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>A description of the contents of the GPX file.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="author" type="personType" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    The person or organization who created the GPX file.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="copyright" type="copyrightType"
            minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Copyright and license information governing use of the file.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="link" type="linkType" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    URLs associated with the location described in the file.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="time" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>The creation date of the file.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="keywords" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Keywords associated with the file. Search engines or databases can use
                    this information to classify the data.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="bounds" type="boundsType" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Minimum and maximum coordinates which describe the extent of the
                    coordinates in the file.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="extensions" type="extensionsType" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    You can add extend GPX by adding your own elements from another
                    schema here.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="wptType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            wpt represents a waypoint, point of interest, or named feature on a
            map.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <!-- elements must appear in this order -->
        <!-- Position info -->
        <xsd:element name="ele" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Elevation (in meters) of the point.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="time" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Creation/modification timestamp for element. Date and time in are in Univeral
                    Coordinated Time (UTC), not local time! Conforms to ISO 8601
                    specification for date/time representation. Fractional seconds are
                    allowed for millisecond timing in tracklogs.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="magvar" type="degreesType" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Magnetic variation (in degrees) at the point
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="geoidheight" type="xsd:decimal"
            minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Height (in meters) of geoid (mean sea level) above WGS84 earth
                    ellipsoid. As defined in NMEA GGA message.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <!-- Description info -->
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    The GPS name of the waypoint. This field will be transferred to and
                    from the GPS. GPX does not place restrictions on the length of
                    this field or the characters contained in it. It is up to the
                    receiving application to validate the field before sending it to
                    the GPS.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="cmt" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>GPS waypoint comment. Sent to GPS as comment.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="desc" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    A text description of the element. Holds additional information
                    about the element intended for the user, not the GPS.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="src" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Source of data. Included to give user some idea of reliability and
                    accuracy of data. "Garmin eTrex", "USGS quad Boston North", e.g.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="link" type="linkType" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Link to additional information about the
                    waypoint.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="sym" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Text of GPS symbol name. For interchange with other programs, use the
                    exact spelling of the symbol as displayed on the GPS. If the GPS
                    abbreviates words, spell them out.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Type (classification) of the waypoint.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <!-- Accuracy info -->
        <xsd:element name="fix" type="fixType" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Type of GPX fix.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="sat" type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger"
            minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Number of satellites used to calculate the GPX fix.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="hdop" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Horizontal dilution of precision.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="vdop" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Vertical dilution of precision.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="pdop" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Position dilution of precision.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="ageofdgpsdata" type="xsd:decimal"
            minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Number of seconds since last DGPS update.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="dgpsid" type="dgpsStationType"
            minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    ID of DGPS station used in differential correction.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="extensions" type="extensionsType"
            minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    You can add extend GPX by adding your own elements from another
                    schema here.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="lat" type="latitudeType" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                The latitude of the point. This is always in decimal degrees, and
                always in WGS84 datum.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="lon" type="longitudeType" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                The longitude of the point. This is always in decimal degrees, and
                always in WGS84 datum.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="rteType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            rte represents route - an ordered list of waypoints representing a
            series of turn points leading to a destination.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>GPS name of route.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="cmt" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>GPS comment for route.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="desc" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Text description of route for user. Not sent to GPS.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="src" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Source of data. Included to give user some idea of reliability and
                    accuracy of data.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="link" type="linkType" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Links to external information about the route.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="number" type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger"
            minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>GPS route number.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Type (classification) of route.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="extensions" type="extensionsType"
            minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    You can add extend GPX by adding your own elements from another
                    schema here.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="rtept" type="wptType" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>A list of route points.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="trkType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            trk represents a track - an ordered list of points describing a path.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>GPS name of track.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="cmt" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>GPS comment for track.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="desc" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>User description of track.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="src" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Source of data. Included to give user some idea of reliability and
                    accuracy of data.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="link" type="linkType" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Links to external information about track.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="number" type="xsd:nonNegativeInteger"
            minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>GPS track number.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Type (classification) of track.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="extensions" type="extensionsType"
            minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    You can add extend GPX by adding your own elements from another
                    schema here.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="trkseg" type="trksegType" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    A Track Segment holds a list of Track Points which are logically
                    connected in order. To represent a single GPS track where GPS
                    reception was lost, or the GPS receiver was turned off, start a
                    new Track Segment for each continuous span of track data.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="extensionsType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            You can add extend GPX by adding your own elements from another schema
            here.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:any namespace="##other" processContents="lax" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    You can add extend GPX by adding your own elements from another
                    schema here.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:any>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="trksegType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            A Track Segment holds a list of Track Points which are logically
            connected in order. To represent a single GPS track where GPS
            reception was lost, or the GPS receiver was turned off, start a new
            Track Segment for each continuous span of track data.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <!-- elements must appear in this order -->
        <xsd:element name="trkpt" type="wptType" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    A Track Point holds the coordinates, elevation, timestamp, and
                    metadata for a single point in a track.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="extensions" type="extensionsType"
            minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    You can add extend GPX by adding your own elements from another
                    schema here.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="copyrightType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Information about the copyright holder and any license governing use of this
            file. By linking to an appropriate license, you may place your data
            into the public domain or grant additional usage rights.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <!-- elements must appear in this order -->
        <xsd:element name="year" type="xsd:gYear" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Year of copyright.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="license" type="xsd:anyURI" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Link to external file containing license text.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="author" type="xsd:string" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>Copyright holder (TopoSoft, Inc.)
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="linkType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            A link to an external resource (Web page, digital photo, video clip,
            etc) with additional information.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <!-- elements must appear in this order -->
        <xsd:element name="text" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Text of hyperlink.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="type" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Mime type of content (image/jpeg)
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="href" type="xsd:anyURI" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>URL of hyperlink.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="emailType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            An email address. Broken into two parts (id and domain) to help
            prevent email harvesting.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:attribute name="id" type="xsd:string" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>id half of email address (billgates2004)
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="domain" type="xsd:string" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>domain half of email address (hotmail.com)
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="personType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>A person or organization.</xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <!-- elements must appear in this order -->
        <xsd:element name="name" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Name of person or organization.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="email" type="emailType" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Email address.</xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="link" type="linkType" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>
                    Link to Web site or other external information about person.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ptType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            A geographic point with optional elevation and time. Available for
            use by other schemas.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <!-- elements must appear in this order -->
        <xsd:element name="ele" type="xsd:decimal" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>The elevation (in meters) of the point.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="time" type="xsd:dateTime" minOccurs="0">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>The time that the point was recorded.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
    <xsd:attribute name="lat" type="latitudeType" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                The latitude of the point. Decimal degrees, WGS84 datum.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="lon" type="longitudeType" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                The latitude of the point. Decimal degrees, WGS84 datum.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="ptsegType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            An ordered sequence of points. (for polygons or polylines, e.g.)
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:sequence>
        <!-- elements must appear in this order -->
        <xsd:element name="pt" type="ptType" minOccurs="0"
            maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:documentation>Ordered list of geographic points.
                </xsd:documentation>
            </xsd:annotation>
        </xsd:element>
    </xsd:sequence>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:complexType name="boundsType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Two lat/lon pairs defining the extent of an element.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:attribute name="minlat" type="latitudeType" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>The minimum latitude.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="minlon" type="longitudeType" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>The minimum longitude.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="maxlat" type="latitudeType" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>The maximum latitude.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
    <xsd:attribute name="maxlon" type="longitudeType" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>The maximum longitude.</xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
</xsd:complexType>
<xsd:simpleType name="latitudeType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            The latitude of the point. Decimal degrees, WGS84 datum.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="-90.0" />
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="90.0" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="longitudeType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            The longitude of the point. Decimal degrees, WGS84 datum.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="-180.0" />
        <xsd:maxExclusive value="180.0" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="degreesType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Used for bearing, heading, course. Units are decimal degrees, true (not
            magnetic).
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="0.0" />
        <xsd:maxExclusive value="360.0" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="fixType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            Type of GPS fix. none means GPS had no fix. To signify "the fix info is
            unknown, leave out fixType entirely. pps = military signal used
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="none" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="2d" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="3d" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="dgps" />
        <xsd:enumeration value="pps" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:simpleType name="dgpsStationType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>Represents a differential GPS station.
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:integer">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="0" />
        <xsd:maxInclusive value="1023" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

This is then marshalled into Java classes. My problem is that I need to extend this schema so I can use:

```
 <extensions><speed>21.9432334</speed></extensions>
```

I have tried several different things, like creating a new complex type with an `<xs:extension base="NAME">` tag.

I am VERY new to xsd and JAXB and been handed a task which i have no idea about. Hoping someone can help me out here.

See https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-match/topics/file-formats.html

Thanks for your support. Please feel free to ask questions

Comment: always one who does this!

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Needed to add

```
</xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:simpleType name="speedType">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:documentation>
            The speed of the point. Metres per second
        </xsd:documentation>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:decimal">
        <xsd:minInclusive value="-125.2" />
        <xsd:maxExclusive value="125.2" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

and then

```
<xsd:attribute name="speed" type="speedType" use="required">
        <xsd:annotation>
            <xsd:documentation>
                The speed of the the point. Metres per second.
            </xsd:documentation>
        </xsd:annotation>
    </xsd:attribute>
```

to the complex type :)